# How to Access a custom folder outside of public folder in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, directory, laravel-5.6

Directory structure

```
root----------www------public
  |-----------area-----laravel App
  |-----------other----my.html
```

How to access **my.html** file that is inside the **'other'** folder in laravel App?

How can I include **my.html** file in a view ?

Comment: explain your question properly that what you want and what is the problem without that it did not make any seance

Comment: @Antu Actually I have 3 folder in root directory one is www where I saved my public folder of laravel . other is area folder where i saved laravel app (without public folder) . And I have existing project lunched in other folder in root. so how to access that other project folder to get a html file access?

Comment: Dear @saibal please update your question, not in the comment